# How to merge all integer arrays from all records into single array in postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a column which is of type integer array. How can I merge all of them into a single integer array?

For example: If I execute query:

```
select column_name from table_name
```

I get result set as:

```
-[RECORD 1]----------
column_name | {1,2,3}
-[RECORD 2]----------
column_name | {4,5}
```

How can I get `{1,2,3,4,5}` as final result?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You could use [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to open up the arrays and then [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) to put them back together:

```
select array_agg(c)
from (
  select unnest(column_name)
  from table_name
) as dt(c);
```

Comment: Likely much more efficient than mine, but won't necessarily retain element order; you'd have to use `with ordinality` for that.

Comment: @Craig: Which version of PostgreSQL has WITH ORDINALITY? Anyway, custom aggregates are kinda' cool

Comment: Added in PostgreSQL 9.4, so "coming soon". I'm too used to working with git master...

Comment: [Details for `WITH ORDINALITY`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Answer (score 25):

Define a trivial custom aggregate:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_cat_agg(anyarray) (
  SFUNC=array_cat,
  STYPE=anyarray
);
```

and use it:

```
WITH v(a) AS ( VALUES (ARRAY[1,2,3]), (ARRAY[4,5,6,7]))
SELECT array_cat_agg(a) FROM v;
```

If you want a particular order, put it within the aggregate call, i.e. `array_cat_agg(a ORDER BY ...)`

This is <strike>roughly `O(n log n)` for n rows (I think)</strike> `O(n²)` so it is unsuitable for long sets of rows. For better performance you'd need to write it in C, where you can use the more efficient (but horrible to use) C API for PostgreSQL arrays to avoid re-copying the array each iteration.

Comment: FWIW this aggregate runs in quadratic time `O(n^2)` and so isn't suitable for large datasets. source: I used it on some large datasets in production and had to rip it out =)

Comment: @JohnBledsoe I'm surprised it's `O(n^2)`, are you sure? It copies the whole array once per iteration, including all prior members, when it constructs a new one. Either way, it'll still be plenty slow for long inputs.

Comment: I've been out of CS school for a long time, so I'm not sure =) but yeah copying an N-length array N times is `O(n^2)` IIRC.

Comment: @JohnBledsoe The array starts at length 1. Each time you copy it, it grows by 1 element. Assuming each input array is of the same length (treated as 1 element for this purpose): 1 elements copied @ n=1 . 3 elements copied @ n=2 . 6 elements copied @ n=3. 10 elements copied @ n=4. It's a series sum n∑n . Which is (n·n)/2 or n²/2 .. so O(n^2). You're quite right. Pg doesn't have mutable arrays at the SQL level so you'd need to use a PL (say, Python with `numpy` or `intarray`) or use C to do it more efficiently.

Comment: Not sure about the mathematics here, but from my experience it was very slow too. Took forever (I gave up after 30 seconds) on a 300K rows table, while mu-is-too-short's solution took 215ms.

Comment: I did manage to optimize your solution to 2.5 seconds by grouping the rows ( https://gist.github.com/ezra100/1ab9be45eb21569b5aa0e6212495b1c9 ), but mu-is-too-short's is simpler and faster

Answer (score 3):

to **merge** arrays you can use `||` operator [more](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html#:%7E:text=%7C%7C-,array%2Dto%2Darray%20concatenation,-ARRAY%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%20%7C%7C%20ARRAY%5B4%2C5%2C6)

to put result in **flat list** use `uunest` [func](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html#:%7E:text=unnest(anyarray%2C%20anyarray%20%5B%2C%20...%5D))

[example:](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x5CDdMjLQJ4a4UhANEGG8V/0)

```
select unnest(ARRAY[1,2] || ARRAY[3,2] || ARRAY[4,5]) as number;
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

```
string_to_array(string_agg(array_to_string(column_name ,','),','),',')
```

This can be some clue for your situation.
I've done like this.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lateral subquery` for that:

```
select array_agg(u.a)
from (values (array[1, 2, 3]), (array[4, 5])) t (a)
    join lateral unnest(t.a) u (a) on true;
```

Answer (score -2):

The only way you can do this is inside a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION merge_arrays() RETURNS int[] AS $$
DECLARE
  this record;
  res  int[];
BEGIN
  FOR this IN
    SELECT column_name FROM table_name
  LOOP
    array_cat(res, this.column_name);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN res;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then you can

```
SELECT merge_arrays();
```

to get the result you are looking for.

This of course hard-codes your table definition into the function, which may (or may not) be an issue. In addition, you may want to put a `WHERE` clause in the loop query to restrict the records whose arrays you want to append; you might use an additional function parameter to do this.

Keep in mind that you might get a really large array as your table increases in size and that may affect performance. Do you really need all sub-arrays from all records in one large array? Have a look at your application and see if you can do the merge at that level, rather than in a single query.